# How to identify columns that contain only NULL values?

Tags: python, pandas, null, jupyter-notebook

I have a CSV file with 400+ columns. Many of them have no records. I am using the following to display *all* columns and to show a count of records per column:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df.isna().sum()
```

The result set is only showing the first 5 and the last 5 columns. I need to see *all* 400+ columns, with the sum of NULLs for each.

How do I do this? I'm using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.

Comment: From my experience (which is not vast), `pandas` default representations show only the edges of large frames. The data is all in the result, but in order to facilitate understanding, only what a user can perceive is displayed. If you iterate the data, or somehow reduce it further, you can see it's all there.

Comment: Thanks, Amitai. Is there a simple code I can use to show the name of each column with the sum of NULLs for each column?

Answer (score 0):

As @Amitai Irron pointed out in his comment, it'll only show you the edges of the frame, however, you can change Jupyter options for that print to set the rows/columns diplay max to none which will show you all of the datatframe:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df) #or display(df)
```